# Missing SEAM_HOME environment variable fails Ant build

Tags: ant, jboss

My machine just had its hard drive re-imaged so I'm trying to rebuild it. At this point, I am trying to execute an ant script which has worked for years. Not anymore. When the script compiles the `javac` errors because it can't find a directory.

The error is...

> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\Users\WHeckle\Documents\temp\6.9.2\build-tceq.xml:92: C:\Users\WHeckle\Documents\temp\6.9.2\${env.SEAM_HOME}\lib does not exist.

It looks like it is concatenating the current directory with seam_home and using it as a library reference to the compiler.

I am at a loss to explain the behavior. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Ant script expects to find a Windows environment variable named `SEAM_HOME`.

To get the script to work...

- Close any Command Prompts that are open.
- Create a `SEAM_HOME` Windows system environment variable (if this step is unclear, search Google to find instructions on how to do this for your version of Windows).
- Open a new Command Prompt.
- Run `echo %SEAM_HOME%` in the Command Prompt to confirm that the environment variable is set.
- Re-run your Ant script.

`SEAM_HOME` appears to be related to JBoss. For an example of what the value of `SEAM_HOME` can be, see [this JBossDeveloper forum post](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/205798?tstart=0&_sscc=t).